# Random stops in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2012

This is probably pretty simple, but it's driving me crazy. Occasionally when I'm running a project from Visual Studio 2012, it will decide to stop at a random line:

[image: Visual Studio]

Then every single time that I run that project thereafter, it stops at that same line so I have to keep clicking continue while I'm trying to test. Is there a way to prevent/fix this?

Comment: Debug menu -> Windows -> BreakPoints -> Delete all breakPoints.

Comment: You might also want to clean the project and rebuild.